# Custom UITableView, created on ViewController - no data displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a ViewController, which has few text & lable controls

Based on value entered in a text control, I am creating (custom) UITableView and attaching it on VwCtrl as below

```
myUITableViewClass *grid = [[myUITableViewClass alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
grid.view.frame = CGRectMake(20.f, 322.f, 280.f, 186.f);
[self.presentedViewController addChildViewController:grid];
[self.view addSubview:grid.view];
```

At runtime, I am able to see grid created - no data displayed!

I have checked for data in method cellForRowAtIndexPath - no issue.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    //NSLog (@"Cell created");
}

NSLog (@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"ID"]) ;
cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"ID"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Name"];

return cell;
```

Comment: It looks you haven't set your `UITableViewDataSource` delegate on your table instance?

Comment: Thanks foggzilla. I have tried to add <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> in both header files of ViewController & myUITableViewClass - no luck!

Comment: By <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> You are just conforming to the guidelines(technically called protocols), but not defining the datasource of the table.
  Just before [self.presentedViewController addChildViewController:grid];
[self.view addSubview:grid.view]; 
add this code "grid.datasource = self;"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to assign the tableview's dataSource for it to call `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
myUITableViewClass *grid = [[myUITableViewClass alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
grid.view.frame = CGRectMake(20.f, 322.f, 280.f, 186.f);
grid.dataSource = self;
grid.delegate = self;
[self.presentedViewController addChildViewController:grid];
[self.view addSubview:grid.view];
```

You'll also need to implement the other required UITableViewDataSource method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` if you haven't already.

Additionally if you want to implement any of the UITableViewDelegate methods such as `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` you'll need to set the tableview's delegate as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever set yourself to be the delegate and data source on your?

```
myUITableViewClass *grid = [[myUITableViewClass alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
grid.view.frame = CGRectMake(20.f, 322.f, 280.f, 186.f);
grid.delegate = self;
grid.delegate= self;
[self.presentedViewController addChildViewController:grid];
[self.view addSubview:grid.view];
```